# Gamma function for $\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n/2-2}e^{-x}dx$

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals, exponential-function, gamma-function

To solve the integral i have made a change of variable to arrive to gamma function. But the exponential value of the new variable x is n/2-2. How can i continue?
\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
n\theta \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\frac{(\theta t)^{n/2-1}}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}e^{-\theta t/2}dt 
\end{split}
\end{equation*}
This is my change of variable:
\begin{align*}
x=\frac{\theta}{2}t \quad & \frac{2x}{\theta}=t \quad & x=0 \;\; x=\infty \\
dx=\frac{\theta}{2}dt \quad &\frac{2dx}{\theta}=dt \quad & t=0 \;\; t=\infty
\end{align*}

\begin{equation*}
\begin{split}
n\theta \int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{t}\frac{(\theta t)^{n/2-1}}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)}e^{-\theta t/2}dt &= \frac{n\theta^{2}}{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{(\theta)^{n/2-2}}{2^{n/2}}t^{n/2-2}e^{-\theta t/2}dt= \frac{n\theta^2}{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{\theta^{n/2-2}}{2^{n/2}}\frac{2^{n/2-2}}{\theta^{n/2-2}}x^{n/2-2}e^{-x}\frac{2}{\theta}dx \\
&=\frac{n\theta^2}{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_{0}^{\infty}\frac{2}{\theta}\;x^{n/2-2}e^{-x}dx=
\frac{2n\theta}{\Gamma(n/2)}\int_{0}^{\infty}x^{n/2-2}e^{-x}dx
\end{split}
\end{equation*}

But in the last integral, I have been looking for a gamma function for that form of integral but nothing

Comment: This integral is the very definition of $\Gamma (\frac n 2-1)$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The last integral is precisely $\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)$. Do you se why? Then, you have:

$$\frac{2n\theta}{\Gamma(n/2)}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)=\frac{2n\theta\cdot\Gamma(n/2-1)}{(n/2-1)\Gamma(n/2-1)}=\frac{4n\theta}{n-2}$$With the derivation valid for any real $n>2$.

Comment: right now i don´t see why that identity is equal to my last integral. Can you give me a link where I can see that identity?

Comment: Which identity do you mean? @Luther As $(n/2-2)=(n/2-1)-1$, by (one) definition of the gamma function: $$\int_0^\infty x^{(n/2)-2}e^{-x}\,\mathrm{d}x=\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}-1\right)$$

Comment: I also used $x\Gamma(x)=\Gamma(x+1)$, which is a very fundamental property - it is why it is thought of as a generalisation of the factorial.

Comment: True.Today I'm very tired. Thank you. I've seen how it's done.

Comment: @Luther No problem, we’ve all been there